# Magento Module development 1.7

Tags: php, module, magento-1.7

I've recently started looking into developing on Magento, there is however one small road bump I've run right into. This is regarding the lack of documentation on making custom modules.

I've found a load of guides for older versions,even tried following one to the letter and it didn't break anything, but nothing at all changed.

Are there any decent references for 1.7? Magento has such a bastardized way of doing everything That without a framework to follow when i at least do it the first time I'm never going to get anywhere.

I have also tried downloading a module to see how its built, but for now they are generally far too advanced to be helpful for my learning process so any kind of blank database table interfacing module would be a perfect reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much changed between the versions in terms of structure of modules.

A good way to learn is to use a Module creator to generate a basic module for yourself and then tinker with it:

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

You can select different options depending on what you want to include, it's a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very easy tutorial for a basic module creating an event observer which logs every product save action:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

This should give you a first insight into programming a small module.
Generally speaking, most of the examples you can find online for Magento 1.5 or 1.6 will also easily work in 1.7